# Mean Square Estimate problem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

I have to find $\textbf{s}_{MS}$ given

$\textbf{r} = h\textbf{s}+\textbf{n}$

where $h$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $Pr(h=1)=Pr(h=0) = 1/2$ and $\textbf{s}$ and $\textbf{n}$ are independent zero-mean Gaussian random vectors with covariances $P_s$ and $P_n$.

My Attempt:
I know that if $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{s}$ are jointly gaussian, then

\begin{equation}
\textbf{s}_{MS} = \textbf{m}_s+P_{s r}P_{r}^{-1}[r-\textbf{m}_r] \  \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
\end{equation}

where $\textbf{m}_s$ and $\textbf{m}_r$ are the mean vectors of $\textbf{s}$ and $\textbf{r}$

I said that

\begin{align}
P_{sr} &= var(h\textbf{s})\\
&=E^2[h]var(\textbf{s})+E^2[\textbf{s}]var(h)+var(h)var(\textbf{s})\\
&= (1/2)^2 P_s + m_s var(h) + var(h)P_s\\
&= \frac{1}{4}P_s+\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})P_s\\
&= \frac{1}{2}P_s
\end{align}

and that
\begin{align*}
P_r &= var(h\textbf{s}+\textbf{n})\\
&=var(h\textbf{s})+var(\textbf{n})\\
&= \frac{1}{2}P_s+P_n
\end{align*}

So plugging back into $(*)$, I get,

\begin{align*}
\hat{\textbf{s}}_{MS} &= \frac{1}{2}P_s\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}P_s+P_n}\textbf{r}\\
&= \frac{P_s\textbf{r}}{P_s+2P_n}
\end{align*}

The main thing I am not sure about is if my calculations of $P_sr$ and $P_r$ are correct.

It is rather straight forward if $h$ were deterministic because then I can just use the Gaussian linear model to solve the problem and I tried adopting the method to solve that problem here but am not sure if I have made a leap somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your question that $s_{MS} = \mathbb{E}(s | r)$. I will also assume that $h$ is independent of all other variables. First note that $\mathbb{E}(s|r)$ is a marginal distribution over $h$. Thus, let's deploy iterated expectation:

$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(s|r) &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(s|r, h)]\\
                &= \mathbb{P}(h=0).\mathbb{E}(s|r,h=0) + \mathbb{P}(h=1).\mathbb{E}(s|r,h=1)\\
                &= \frac{1}{2}.\mathbb{E}(s|r,h=0) + \frac{1}{2}.\mathbb{E}(s|r,h=1)\\
                &= \frac{1}{2}.\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(n)}_{\text{$r=n$ when $h=0$ and $s$ is indep of $n$}} + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}(s|r,h=1).
\end{align}$

I'm not sure your question is clearly enough stated that I can be sure I'm answering your question...